# Overwriting Box.com file from API

Tags: vb.net, api, box

Currently I am using VB.net to upload  files to BOX API, But having issue overwriting a file. I want to use Version upload But where do I need to add the Path parameter or any other necessary  parameters to accomplish this? :

```
Dim tokenProvider As New TokenProvider(clientID, clientSecret)
boxManager.CreateFile("0", "file_name", (file_Stream))
```

Thanks

Comment: Do a little research.  This took all of 6 seconds to find.  https://developer.box.com/v2.0/reference#upload-a-new-version-of-a-file

Comment: I spent hours and I have seen this page many times. My issue is that I am not using curl. Using .net and  I don't know how to pass the parameter to the API